# How to set a caption for a Checkbox in a FormLayout in Vaadin Flow

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

In `FormLayout` all my components have a caption label just above the component except for the `Checkbox`. So for example if I have a row with just a single `Checkbox` (the other column is empty or the Checkbox question spans two columns) then it's very disproportionally close to the row above. Is there a way to add a caption like the other components? In my case the `Checkbox` is a question whereas the caption is just a simple title of what the `Checkbox` represents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
// configure to your liking responsively
formLayout.setResponsiveSteps(new FormLayout.ResponsiveStep("0", 2, FormLayout.ResponsiveStep.LabelsPosition.TOP));

formLayout.addFormItem(new Checkbox(), "Any label you want aligned with other labels");
```

Comment: Interesting. I thought the responsiveStep was top by default on FormLayout.